# Couldn't get the screenshot of an element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, screenshot

I'm trying to get the screenshot of the "Next" button on the Gmail login page with the below code.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    WebElement signupButton= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']"));

    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

    int width = signupButton.getSize().getWidth();
    int height = signupButton.getSize().getHeight();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(width, height);

    Point p = signupButton.getLocation();

    BufferedImage dest = image.getSubimage(p.getX(), p.getY(), width, height);

    ImageIO.write(dest, "png", screenshot);

    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Screenshots\\loginButton.png"));
```

The screenshot taken was empty. There is no element in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that anymore. In latest versions of Selenium now you can take screen shot of element straight away as the WebElement interface API already has that ability. take a look at below example:

```
element.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']"));

// Get entire page screenshot
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

// Get the location of element on the page
        Point point = ele.getLocation();

// Get width and height of the element
        int windth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
        int height = ele.getSize().getHeight();

// Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
        BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
                windth, height);
        ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

// Copy the element screenshot to disk
        File screenshotLocation = new File("C:\\New folder\\Capture.png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
```

Comment: Hi... Thanks for your reply. I want to take the screenshot of the "Next" button.

Comment: @learningQA: Please find updated solution. Once confirm kindly hit upvote button and accept my answer